# Pull up/Pull down power consumption

Tags: microcontroller, pullup, pulldown, power-consumption

For a microcontroller, does pulling up a GPIO pin consumes more power than pulling it down? (I've got the option to pull a GPIO pin up or down)

Comment: Any particular microcontroller?

Comment: This is too broad to be answered. There may be a difference, or no difference at all, depending on the use case.

Comment: Yes @RogerRowland MSP430.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It doesn't consume power if the signal is in the state it is pulled to, i.e. HIGH if pulled up or LOW if pulled down.

Therefore it just depends on the state the signal is in **most of the time** (assuming that pull up current equals pull down current):
If the signal is **LOW** most of the time it consumes more power if it is **pulled up** and vice versa.